# Angular 2 & 4 - ng-pick-datetime overwriting component stylesheet

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli

I'm using Angular CLI (ng4), and I'm implementing ng-pick-datetime (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime).

Everything loads as expected and it's quite a nice module.

But, my associated component stylesheet seems to be getting loaded before the module loads it's own stylesheet.  Therefore overwriting any styles I declare in the component's stylesheet.

**component.css**

```
.owl-dateTime-dialog {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border: 1px solid #000 !important;
}
```

[See example here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DSux.jpg)

Not too sure where to go from here.  Surely I've implemented the module incorrectly, as to why it's stylesheet is loading after the component's???

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

**select-date-and-time.component.ts**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DateTimePickerModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-date-and-time',
  templateUrl: './select-date-and-time.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-date-and-time.component.css']
})
export class SelectDateAndTimeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your css classes in global **styles.css**

Comment: Thanks @MiR.  Wasn't sure if anyone was going to reply to this one but that is indeed how I did fix it.